# how to select value like an IF in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have some row data that may or not have a string value, and I want to add another column that has a 1 or 0 based on if the string is present or not. This is part of a big grouping/aggregation query, so wondering how best to do that?

basically if it was python:

```py
        if row.get('intent_detail'):
            row['intent_detail_flag'] = 1
        else:
            row['intent_detail_flag'] = 0
        return row
```

I was going to try a `CASE` - is that the best way?

```
            CASE
                WHEN (max(intent_detail) IS NOT NULL)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END as intent_detail_flag,
```

Comment: Your method is fine, but you can get rid of the `case` and just return a boolean.

Comment: yes i was wondering if there's some other method with an IF. i want integers so i can do averages etc later.

Comment: . . Booleans are pretty flexible too.  I would recommend `case` over `if` because `case` is more flexible and it is Standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` with `IFNULL`

```
IF(IFNULL(MAX(intent_detail),0)>0,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery you could use [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting) in conjunction with a CASE statement. So you could flag integers or numerics like this:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `data` AS (SELECT '2' AS `val`
              UNION ALL SELECT 'not a number'
              UNION ALL SELECT '4.6')
SELECT `val`,
        CASE WHEN SAFE_CAST(`val` AS INT64) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS `is_int64`,
        CASE WHEN SAFE_CAST(`val` AS NUMERIC) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS `is_numeric`
FROM `data`;
```

SAFE_CAST returns NULL if the value can not be converted, so if you're running a big grouping query you don't actually need the intermediate step of a flag at all:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `data` AS (SELECT '2' AS `val`
              UNION ALL SELECT 'not a number'
              UNION ALL SELECT '4.6')
SELECT AVG(SAFE_CAST(`val` AS NUMERIC))
FROM `data`;
```

.. returns 3.3 (not 2.2) because the [AVG function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#avg) ignores NULL values.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a computed column like this;

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
    (
    intent_detail varchar(100) NULL,
    intent_detail_flag  AS CASE WHEN intent_detail IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED 
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Making it persistent means that it will only need to recalculate the field if you update the value of intent_details.

Comment: oh interesting. I'm using bigquery, it's not clear if that is supported. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501001/how-create-a-calculated-column-in-google-bigquery

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise it was big query.  I'm not familiar with it enough to say if you can do calculated columns but as you suggested you can do it within the query with CASE WHEN intent_detail IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as intent_detail_flag.